# Run .sql file from batch file

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file

I'm new to batch files and would like to execute sql script from the batch file. Please can someone assist.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `sqlcmd` command line tool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sqlcmd.exe` from the DOS prompt.  If you run `sqlcmd -?` from the DOS prompt the program will tell you the command line parameters.  Here's an example

```
sqlcmd -S MyDbServer -d DatabaseName -E -i "MyScript.sql"
```

The `-E` tells `sqlcmd` to use "trusted authentication" meaning your Windows login.  If you're not using Windows Authentication then you'll want to use the `-U` and `-P` parameters.